# Powershell script stopping .mp3

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to create a basic powershell script to run on startup to narrate speech and then play a song via windows media player.  It runs successfully but the .mp3 file cuts off right after the speech is done. I'd like to run another 10-15 seconds.  Below is my syntax.

`Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speak.Speak('Welcome home sir. You will need to pay attention the entire duration. With every passing hour I will monitor your actions. Enjoy your time sir. Thank you for your time today and I hope you accomplish everything you set your mind to. The world is your oyster.')`

Any ideas to make it run longer?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not going to make it any faster. The OS has to complete the login process before it will start to run your script. That includes loading the user profile preferences, setting up the environment, and other startup tasks. Why does it not starting within 10 seconds matter? When I start my computer,and log in, it takes a few seconds before it becomes usable even manually. I don't expect anything any faster than that because it's normal. In your case, it has to load the support for VBScript as well before your script can be executed in addition to what normally happens.

Comment: Thanks Ken! I figured that was the case, I actually converted my vbs script to a powershell script so everything runs in the background, now I'm running into the issue of the .mp3 stopping a littler earlier than my liking.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. Stop trying to escape the Windows startup process, because it's not going to work. Windows *has* to load drivers and profile information and finish other setup when a user logs in. You're not going to run around what is required by the OS. If you restart your computer, log in, and the second the desktop appears try to open the start menu, you'll find you don't get a response for several seconds because the OS isn't ready yet. Your script (whether it's VBScript or Powershell) isn't going to perform any better. You're wasting your time here.